# Why blue vertical line shown on left edge while loading html <blockquote> contents in TextView android

Tags: android, html, css

I have an app in which I shows some html content in textview. So when the textView renders all html content and it will show this.

After some searches I found that blockquote cause this issue. I want to style blockquote content like p tag inside blockquote text.

[image: here is the image]

I want to remove/style blue vertical line which is present at left edge corner of textview.

I try to get description of articles and here is html content.

```
 <p>Razorpay, an online payments solution provider, has announced that it has raised $20 million in its Series B funding round. The round was led by Silicon Valley-based accelerator Y Combinator’s YC Continuity Fund and existing investor Tigers Global. Along with them, Matrix Partners has also participated in this round.</p>
  <p>The Bangalore-based startup now plans to use the freshly raised funds to push new products which it launched in September last year including facilities like recurring payments, automation of bank transfers like NEFT, and invoice management as part of its new strategy under Razorpay 2.0.</p>
  <p>Harshil Mathur, co-founder and CEO of the company, said:</p>
  <blockquote><p>We are looking to expand our team and hire heads for new business verticals. About 50% of new hires will be in technology and the product teams while the rest would be for business roles.</p></blockquote>
  <p>Anu Hariharan, Partner at Y Combinator’s Continuity Fund said,</p>
  <blockquote><p>We are excited to participate in Razorpay’s Series B round. The company’s vision and execution over the last 3 years has shown tremendous results, especially for an India focused SAAS company. With the online and digital payment space going through a massive transformation in India, their business is only going to grow further. There is now an inherent need for better systems, process and infrastructure in place and we are confident that Razorpay is perfectly suited to make the most of the changing landscape.</p></blockquote>
  <p>At present, it has about 130 people and it could hire over 70 people during this year. Mathur said the company, as part of the new strategy, is looking to generate at least 30% of company’s revenue from these new launches.</p>
  <p>The latest round takes the total amount the startup has raised to $31.6 million The company last raised undisclosed funding from American payments and financial services company MasterCard, in July 2016. At the same time, the startup also became the second Indian company to be selected for the US-based Y-Combinator accelerator programme.</p>
  <p>Founded in 2013 by Harshil Mathur and Shashank Kumar, Razorpay aims to onboard new merchants and increase the base to about 2 lakh by the end of 2018. It claimed to have grown at a rate of about 30-35% per month and has about 65,000 merchants on its platform.</p>
  <p>Razorpay has been backed by 33 angel investors, including Kunal Bahl and Rohit Bansal (Snapdeal founders); Abhay Singhal, Amit Gupta and Naveen Tewari (InMobi founders), Kunal Shah and Sandeep Tandon (Freecharge founders), former chief product officer of Flipkart Punit Soni, Ram Shriram (board member and an early investor in Google), Justin Kan (Y Combinator partner and Twitch founder).</p>
```

And here is xml layout code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/post_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/share_postBtn"
                        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
                        android:layout_width="25dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                        android:background="@drawable/ic_share"
                        android:backgroundTint="#fff"
                        android:onClick="SharePost"/>

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/save_postBtn"
                        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
                        android:layout_width="25dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"

                        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/share_postBtn"
                        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                        android:backgroundTint="#fff"
                        android:onClick="SavePost"/>

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/minus_tvsize"
                        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
                        android:layout_width="25dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/save_postBtn"
                        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                        android:background="@drawable/ic_minus"
                        android:backgroundTint="#fff"/>
                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/plus_tvsize"
                        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
                        android:layout_width="25dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/minus_tvsize"
                        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                        android:background="@drawable/ic_plus"
                        android:backgroundTint="#fff"/>

                </RelativeLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/post_scrollview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <!-- do not remove below layout  -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/viewA"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtDetailTitle"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/firasans_bold"
                    android:lines="4"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
                    android:layout_gravity="start"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/postFeatImage"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />




                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtDetailDescription"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/firasans_regular"
                    android:layout_gravity="fill"
                    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:ellipsize="marquee"
                    android:lineSpacingExtra="@dimen/_3ssp"
                    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
                    android:paddingStart="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_15ssp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_topScroll"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_up"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:tint="#fff"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:onClick="ScrollTop"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I am loading article description on textview which have  **txtDetailDescription** id

Comment: post your HTML content

Comment: i update my questions and provide html content. here i am try to getting post description from wordpress post .

Comment: yes i checked in html there is not problem

Comment: now post your xml code of this layout

Comment: probably that is how the `<blockquote>` tag is processed within TextView. You can change it by manually overriding the how TextView will handle your `<blockquote>`  tag

Comment: sir i can achieve what i want using webview. but not with standard textview or third party library like htmlTextview. so i want to know why this happens

Comment: you can refer this http://www.hidroh.com/2016/02/27/richtext-textview-versus-webview/

Answer (score -1):

**It's a good way to [load html](http://abhiandroid.com/androidstudio/add-local-html-file-android-studio.html)**

and load html in `TextView` you may user like this

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {
            txtDetailDescription.setText(Html.fromHtml("<h2>Title</h2><br><p>Description here</p>", Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT));
        } else {
            txtDetailDescription.setText(Html.fromHtml("<h2>Title</h2><br><p>Description here</p>"));
        }
```

Comment: I already do this . But not works. The issue is with <blockquote> . I want to style <blockquote> tags through jsoup  so how can I do that??????????.

Comment: sir i can achieve what i want using webview. but not with standard textview or third party library like htmlTextview. so i want to know why this happens.

Comment: thanks for answering but i like webview approach. so i use webview instead of textview.

Comment: its work with webview  -"It's a good way to load html" which i provide link so can you  upvote or right tick ans